# Merge columns in Shinobi grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, shinobi, datagridcolumn

I just wanted to know whether we can make a number of columns to merge to a group and set a group title above these columns? I use `SDataGridColumn` to create the columns. But could not find a way to merge them.

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNFRY.png)

If it is not supported by Shinobi Controlls, how can I achieve this functionality? Just setting UILabel above the columns will not work, as my table has lots of columns that scrolls to right/left. And it is not possible to scroll the UILabel as the Shinobi table scrolls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I contacted the Shinobi support team. Unfortunately they do not support grouping of columns. Can anyone suggest any other way to do this?